# Nebula and its colors

Tags: spectroscopy, spectra, nebula

A Nebula has bright awesome colors that include red, blue, green, orange, white, etc?

They're result of excitation of electrons.

Is there a clear explanation as to which color is attributed to an atom for Color properties in Cosmos!?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, nebulae can often have very distinct colours. What produces those colours can depend on what elements are in the nebula material and what the temperature and density are.

*Generally speaking*, green colours in a nebula are due to forbidden transitions in ionised Oxygen, though can feature the hydrogen $\beta$ Balmer line. Red colours can be due to Hydrogen $\alpha$, but there are also lines due to ionised sulphur and nitrogen that often make contributions.

If you take a spectrum of a nebula it usually completely obvious what elements are responsible, because the spectra consist of very sharp emission lines at the wavelengths that correspond to the well-known electronic transitions in particular species. An example is shown below, which is the spectrum of a typical planetary nebula.
Here, the labels mean the following: OIII means oxygen with its outer two electrons removed; NII is nitrogen with its outer electron removed etc., H$\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the $n=3 \rightarrow 2$, $n=4 \rightarrow 2$ and $n=5 \rightarrow 2$ transition of the hydrogen Balmer series. The wavelength scale is in angstroms where 10 angstroms is 1 nm. So 5000 angstroms is the green part of the spectrum, 6500 angstroms is red and 4000 angstroms is blue.

[image: Typical spectrum of a planetary nebula]